# how to prove that one certificate is issuer of another certificates

Tags: certificate, x509certificate, bouncycastle, x509, digital-certificate

I have two certificate.  One certificate is issuer of another certificate.

how can I see with java code that, my issuer certificate is really issuer?

I know that  AuthorityKeyIdentifier of my certificate and  SubjectKeyIdentifie  of issuer certifiactes must be the same. I **checked** and they are **the same**.

but with java code I have that result:

```java
    CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

    InputStream usrCertificateIn = new FileInputStream("/usr.cer");
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(usrCertificateIn);

    InputStream SiningCACertificateIn = new FileInputStream("/siningCA.cer");
    X509Certificate issuer = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(SiningCACertificateIn);

    byte[] octets = (ASN1OctetString.getInstance(cert.getExtensionValue("2.5.29.35")).getOctets());     
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(octets) + " bouncycastle, AuthorityKeyIdentifier");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cert.getExtensionValue("2.5.29.35")) + "java.security, AuthorityKeyIdentifier");

    octets = ASN1OctetString.getInstance(issuer.getExtensionValue("2.5.29.14")).getOctets();
    System.out.println((Arrays.toString(octets) + "bouncycastle, SubjectKeyIdentifie "));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(issuer.getExtensionValue("2.5.29.14")) + "java.security, SubjectKeyIdentifie ");
```

adn the result is that:

[48, 22, -128, **20, 52, -105, 49, -70, -24, 78, 127, -113, -25, 55, 39, 99, 46, 6, 31, 66, -55, -86, -79, 113**] bouncycastle, **AuthorityKeyIdentifier**

[**4**, 24, 48, 22, -128, **20, 52, -105, 49, -70, -24, 78, 127, -113, -25, 55, 39, 99, 46, 6, 31, 66, -55, -86, -79, 113**]java.security, **AuthorityKeyIdentifier**

and another byte array that **MUST BE THE SAME, BUT IT IS NOT** another bytes is added at the beginning of the array.

[**4, 20, 52, -105, 49, -70, -24, 78, 127, -113, -25, 55, 39, 99, 46, 6, 31, 66, -55, -86, -79, 113**]bouncycastle, **SubjectKeyIdentifie**

[4, 22, **4, 20, 52, -105, 49, -70, -24, 78, 127, -113, -25, 55, 39, 99, 46, 6, 31, 66, -55, -86, -79, 113**]java.security, **SubjectKeyIdentifie**

question 1)
Can I calculates the key Identifiers **to get  the same Arrays**?

question 2)
is there another way in order to prove that **one certificate is issuer of another certificates**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AuthorityKeyIdentifier` and `SubjectKeyIdentifier` are defined differently:

```
AuthorityKeyIdentifier ::= SEQUENCE {
  keyIdentifier             [0] KeyIdentifier           OPTIONAL,
  authorityCertIssuer       [1] GeneralNames            OPTIONAL,
  authorityCertSerialNumber [2] CertificateSerialNumber OPTIONAL  }

SubjectKeyIdentifier ::= KeyIdentifier

KeyIdentifier ::= OCTET STRING
```

> *(sections 4.2.1.1 and 4.2.1.2 of [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.1))*

Thus, merely comparing the extension values cannot work, instead you have to extract the `KeyIdentifier` contents and compare them, e.g. using BouncyCastle ASN.1 helper classes.

BTW, the actual key identifier bytes are only

```
52, -105, 49, -70, -24, 78, 127, -113, -25, 55, 39, 99, 46, 6, 31, 66, -55, -86, -79, 113
```

The 4, 20 before that indicates an OCTET STRING, 20 bytes long. In the AuthorityKeyIdentifier the 4 is replaced by the tag [0] (byte -128) due to implicit tagging.

The 48, 22 before that in your AuthorityKeyIdentifier means (constructed) SEQUENCE, 22 bytes long.

Etc. etc.

Thus,

> Can I calculates the key Identifiers **to get the same Arrays**?

Yes, drill down to the actual KeyIdentifier OCTET STRING values.

> is there another way in order to prove that **one certificate is issuer of another certificates**

Well, you can check whether the signature in the certificate is signed by the private key associated with the assumed issuer certificate by verifying against that certificate's public key.

**PS:** Concerning the question in the comments

> is key identifier's length always 20? is it fixed? may be no, is not it?

No, it is not. The before mentioned [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.1) says:

```
For CA certificates, subject key identifiers SHOULD be derived from
the public key or a method that generates unique values.  Two common
methods for generating key identifiers from the public key are:

  (1) The keyIdentifier is composed of the 160-bit SHA-1 hash of the
       value of the BIT STRING subjectPublicKey (excluding the tag,
       length, and number of unused bits).
  (2) The keyIdentifier is composed of a four-bit type field with
       the value 0100 followed by the least significant 60 bits of
       the SHA-1 hash of the value of the BIT STRING
       subjectPublicKey (excluding the tag, length, and number of
       unused bits).

Other methods of generating unique numbers are also acceptable.
```

I assume your CA uses method 1 (160 bit = 20 bytes) but this is merely a **common method,** not even something explicitly **recommended,** let alone **required.** Thus, no, you cannot count on the identifier being 20 bytes long.

**PPS:** Concerning the question in the comments

> Isn't the signature the only way to truly prove one cert is issued by another?

That is no **prove** of the issuer-issuedBy relation either, it merely proves (at least to a certain degree) that the private key associated with the assumed issuer certificate signed the inspected certificate but there are situations where the same private-public key pair is used in multiple certificates.

In essence you need to do multiple complementary test and even then have to trust the CA not to do weird stuff. Not long ago e.g. the Swisscom changed one of their CA certificates to include an additional extension or critical attribute (I'd have to look up the details; I think someone certifying them demanded that change), and by the certificate signature verification test old signer certificates now seem to be issued by the new CA certificate even though the owners of the signer certificates might not be aware of that new extension/critical attribute.

So eventually real life simply is not as simple as one would like it to be...

Comment: thanks. and is key identifier's length always 20? is it fixed? may be no, is not it?

Comment: "drill down to the actual KeyIdentifier OCTET STRING values." - can give me an example how to do that?

Comment: @LadyBird *is key identifier's length always 20* - No, the size may vary.

Comment: @LadyBird *an example how to drill down* - unfortunately I'm not that much into BC, I use other, commercial, ASN.1 helpers at work. But just like you used `ASN1OctetString.getInstance(...).getOctets()` to retrieve the bytes from an OCTET STRING, there surely are other, analogous helpers for extracting an element from a SEQUENCE or for checking whether some element has the tag [0].

Comment: Isn't the signature the only way to truly prove one cert is issued by another?  The AKI in the "issued" cert could be faked, right?

Comment: @gtrig *Isn't the signature the only way to truly prove one cert is issued by another?* - Even that is not enough, see my edits. But my answer was focused on the difference between AuthorityKeyIdentifier and SubjectKeyIdentifier syntax anyway.

Comment: @mkl True, if the CA does weird things, then all bets are off.  But in theory, if the CA protects its private key, then it should be possible to prove an issued certificate was signed by that private key and therefore, by that CA.

Comment: @gtrig See my edit above concerning the Swisscom (which I doubt to be the only case). Yes, you most likely have the correct organization but not necessarily the correct certificate. Thus, you can not really trust e.g. the issuer certificate's extensions / critical attributes to be known or applicable to the subject.

Answer (score 6):

To prove one certificate was issued by another, you should prove it was signed by the private key corresponding to the public key in the issuing certificate.

Let's call 2 certificates `caCert` and `issuedCert`.  These are of type `X509Certificate`.

The Java code to prove `issuedCert` is signed by the entity represented by `caCert` is quite simple.

```
PublicKey caPubKey = caCert.getPublicKey();

issuedCert.verify(caPubKey);
```

If the [verify](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/cert/Certificate.html#verify%28java.security.PublicKey%29) method returns without throwing an exception, then `issuedCert` was signed by the private key corresponding to the public key in `caCert`.